# Non uniform tables in HTML

Tags: html, html-table

I need to make a table that does not have uniform widths.

Currently I have something like this :

[image: Current Output]

And I need something like this :

[image: Output Needed]

Here's some existing code :

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top">
            <img src="person1" class="cycle" style="height:4.5rem; width:4.5rem; position:relative; top:-4px; float:left">
            <!--SMALL IMAGE-->
        </td>
        <td style="padding-left: 20px;">
            <div class="balloon right" style="float:right;width: 855px;">
                <!--LARGE DIV-->
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="padding-right: 20px;">
            <div class="balloon left" style="float:left;width: 855px;">
                <!--LARGE DIV2 -->
            </div>
        </td>
        <td valign="top">
            <img src="person2" style="height:4.5rem; width:4.5rem; position:relative; top:-4px; float:left" class="cycle">
            <!--SMALL IMAGE2 -->
        </td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please, provide more code. CSS and HTML

Comment: Never use tables for layouts. UI images should be CSS backgrounds on elements, not inline images.

Comment: Do you really want to use a table? Some `div`s and CSS sound like a much better option.

Comment: Actually use "tables" to "not tabular 'things'" is a bad way. Use tables only for tabular data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your main (outer table) render a row with a single cell, place your current table for one person's comment inside this main cell:

```
<table>
  <tr>
     <td>
       <table>
          <tr>
           <td valign="top">
             <img src="person1" class="cycle" style="height:4.5rem; width:4.5rem; position:relative; top:-4px; float:left">
           </td>
           <td style="padding-left: 20px;">
            <div class="balloon right" style="float:right;width: 855px;">
              <!--LARGE DIV-->
            </div>
          </td>
         </tr>
       </table>
     </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>
       <table>
          <tr>
           <td style="padding-right: 20px;">
             <div class="balloon left" style="float:left;width: 855px;">
              <!--LARGE DIV2 -->
             </div>
           </td>
          <td valign="top">
            <img src="person2" style="height:4.5rem; width:4.5rem; position:relative; top:-4px; float:left" class="cycle">
        <!--SMALL IMAGE2 -->
          </td>
         </tr>
       </table>
     </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

This way your main table has 1 row with 1 td, inside that td is a new table that has all the content.
You would have to keep track and toggle the left/right of the image for each row.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on using tables for this functionality, I suggest looking at the `rowspan` and `colspan` attributes for the `tr` and `td` elements.

Personally, I recommend looking at frameworks like Bootstrap, that will allow placing content on the screen dynamically using a grid system, while also supporting responsive design and solving other headaches.

Answer (score -1):

i have a solution for you try this and let me know how it works

add

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

like this

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top">
            <img src="person1" class="cycle" style="height:4.5rem; width:4.5rem; position:relative; top:-4px; float:left">
            <!--SMALL IMAGE-->
        </td>
        <td style="padding-left: 20px;">
            <div class="balloon right" style="float:right;width: 855px;">
                <!--LARGE DIV-->
            </div>
 <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="padding-right: 20px;">
            <div class="balloon left" style="float:left;width: 855px;">
                <!--LARGE DIV2 -->
            </div>
 <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        </td>
        <td valign="top">
            <img src="person2" style="height:4.5rem; width:4.5rem; position:relative; top:-4px; float:left" class="cycle">
            <!--SMALL IMAGE2 -->
        </td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Actually use "tables" to "not tabular 'things'" is a bad way.

Comment: Using tables like this I don't approve of i would suggest to use tables or divs but not both, but the issue is simple the Css is trying to float over a Float (Float will detach from the table) by clear::both it "SHOULD" work the way the OP wants it to

Comment: Standards in the case of structure may be a better way, I'm not talking about "DIVS" I'm just talking about default, use the most right for every thing. Prefer `<TABLE>` for tabular data

Comment: I agree fully, every item has its correct use, you don't use a hammer to turn a screw.

Comment: Thanks for your support to my comment. Note: it was not me who gave you the "negative point" to your answer.

Comment: All good I seem to have collected a hater who is chasing my comments -_-